# Match exactly one of each from set of characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a specific set of characters but 1 and only 1 of each.

For example if the set is `[abcd]`, I want to match string containing these exact characters in any order.

```
abcd  - true
bcad  - true
abc   - false (need all characters)
abbd  - false
abcdd - false
```

From what I understand so far there is no easy way to achieve this with RegEx but no answer was conclusive enough.

Comment: What language are you using? There's no *pattern* in your case, I doubt if regex is the best approach (of course you can use alternation on all combinations.. but that would be horrible).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would think of [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if the same character is not ahead.

```
\b(?:([abcd])(?!\w*?\1)){4}\b
```

- `(?:` opens a [non capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) for repetition
- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `([abcd])` captures one of `[abcd]`
- `(?!\w*?\1)` checks if the captured character is not ahead with any amount of [`\w`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) in between
- `{4}\b` 4  times until another word boundary

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hH4bL1/1)   (works only, if a lookahead is available in your regex flavor)

Comment: I think this is best regex solution for OP ++

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookahead for each character to assert that char is present only once in your regex.

So e.g. for your input chars `abcd` **generate** this regex:

```
^(?=[^a]*a[^a]*$)(?=[^b]*b[^b]*$)(?=[^c]*c[^c]*$)(?=[^d]*d[^d]*$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mL7fA9/1)

^`(?=[^a]*a[^a]*$)` will assert that `a` is present only once in input. and so on for other chars `b,c,d`.

Comment: What if the input is `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` ?

Comment: It will obviously fail since `x,y,z` etc are not present in input but if input has too many characters then generated regex might be too long as well

Comment: It doesn't look beautiful but should do the job efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're trying to solve is checking whether a string is a permutation of "abcd".

You don't want to use regex for every problem you have. It's useful and powerful when you have a *pattern*. Checking if a string is a permutations of "abcd" is not really a "pattern".

The best approach would be using the language's power and construct a solution from the functions available for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just a humble contribution using grep:

```
grep -Px '[abcd]{4}' | grep -vP '(.).*\1'
```

- get a seq of 4 [abcd]
- and remove the lines contining repetitions

Answer (score 1):

See [bobble bubble's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35990180/241211) for a real regex solution (which is sometimes necessary). This answer uses sorting and string equality instead of a single regex:

```js
var set = 'bcad'; // in any order
var tests = [
  'abcd',  // true
  'bcad',  // true
  'abc',   // false (need all characters)
  'abbd',  // false
  'abcdd', // false
];

var setSorted = set.split('').sort().join();

for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  var pass = setSorted == tests[i].split('').sort().join();
  console.log(`${tests[i]}: ${pass}`);
}
```